# Is there any way to open ppt file open in Full screen when I click on anchor link in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have ppt file in the href attribute of an anchor tag.If i click on the Anchor tag the file should open in Full screen.I tried by saving the ppt file in different Formats but nothing worked. Please let me know if any way to do that in Html or using Javascript.

Comment: You can make use of iframe and provide src for that file

Answer (score 0):

Ppt is not an HTML standard so you can't expect to see it in the web page properly, but only if you have a proper viewer installed in the computer, but you can't predict it's behaviour.
Why not export the ppt to HTML and then point a link to it with target="_blank"?

Answer (score 0):

Upload your PowerPoint to [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com) and you can use their API to show it on your website without any add-ons or special software.